Is 遊生夢死 a real saying?
遊生夢死 is the title of a very popular song by the artist Eve. At first when looked it up in the dictionaries I have access to (Daijisen, Daijirin), it seems to be a modification of a classical Chinese phrase, 醉生夢死 (in Shinjitai, 酔生夢死), which is said to be originated in a book titled 程子語錄. Some websites claims it's also found in a book titled 小學 by 嘉言. Regardless, the consensus seems to be that the phrase is 醉生夢死, not 遊生夢死. However, I've recently stumbled on this website that seems to claim 遊生夢死 is a real phrase, and it even goes so far to give example sentences, too. This yoji-jukugo website also lists 遊生夢死 as if it was a real phrase, with attribution to 小學, although from what I Googled, the link between 遊生夢死 and 小學 is only Chinese-whispered across Japanese websites. Chinese websites, on the other hand, only show a link between 醉生夢死 and 小學.
So, is 遊生夢死 a real saying? Or somebody just took artistic license and modified 醉生夢死?
Edit: I didn't think of a corpus search, but since the user broccoli forest suggested the possibility of AI-generated content, I looked up 遊生夢死 on Google Books, and it seems to have been used by some writers as far back as 1951. One 1997 book titled 使える四字熟語  claims that the old reading for 酔生夢死 was すいせいぼうし, not すいせいむし as listed in modern dictionaries. I don't have full access to this book so I have no idea why it also includes 遊生夢死. Usage citations for 酔生夢死 remain vanishingly scant, so I'm still not quite convinced it's an idiomatic expression, rather than something made up and quoted by writers.

It's difficult to prove a phrase does not exist, but as far as I searched across Chinese Text Project, 漢籍全文資料庫, and 漢籍リポジトリ, there is no such usage, so I can at least safely say that it has no major reference.
In fact, the combination 遊(游)生 is already rare except "sojourning student". Although 遊夢 or 夢遊 is an established phrase to mean "wander in dream" so that the idiom would not be ill-sounding as Chinese either, it is probably just coined by the artist.
It is reported recently that some internet resources contain AI-generated words that does not exist, so I recommend not trusting unauthenticated word list sites too much.
Update: After looking at the edit, I further searched on NDL Digital Collections and got a handful results, all from works by 渡辺一夫, a researcher and translator of French literature. Namely, it only seems to appear on two unique works: one from his translation in 1938 and another from his essay in 1951, which reprinted on a famous literary magazine 群像. Now I suspect that it is in his personal vocabulary and  included in a recent dictionary because it occurred in 群像, which is often used as a source of corpora.
For your reference, the usage in the 1938 book goes:

彼がアフリカ騎兵になつたのも、正しく戰ふ爲であつたのだ。――然し、カッソンケ族の娘一匹の魔力にかゝつて、小さな白い家の中で、ぐんなりして、遊生夢死の生活をしに來たのでは斷じてなかつたのだ！……（『アフリカ騎兵』）
C’était bien pour se battre qu’il s’était fait spahi, — et non pour aller languir, atone, dans une petite maison blanche, sous les sortilèges d’une fille khassonkée ! ... (Le roman d’un spahi, Pierre Loti)


Don't you mean "wander in dream"? Anyway, when it comes to the artist Eve, it's pretty clear that he uses words unorthodoxly, given that the reading for 遊生夢死 is ゆうせいぼうし, not *ゆうせいむし, which is quite unusual. What's troublesome is the claims made by websites unaffiliated with Eve.

@Vun-HughVaw Oops, it seems I'm keeping misspelling that word.

@Vun-HughVaw As a sidenote, ぼう is the 漢音 of 夢, that is, technically the most orthodox reading for words from Chinese classics.

I don't thinking being kan'on has anything to do with being orthodox. Kan'on is more common, but for multiple commonly used kanji, only their goon are intuitive. For 夢, the goon む is overwhelmingly more common and is still used to create new compounds, thus "orthodox".

If 遊生夢死 is indeed this rare and was seemingly constructed by an author, I guess it's not a "real" saying in any practical sense. Perhaps Eve came across that author's works somehow, or perhaps he indepently came up with it on his own.

@Vun-HughVaw There actually is "orthodox" rules for that matter (see Which readings are used for 漢文？). Just too pedantic for laypeople to remember, like octopodes as the plural of octopus. The modern choice of "de facto" standard reading is another matter. It sometimes comes from 漢音, other times 呉音, or 唐宋音, or even one with no etymological ground (慣用音).
